# The module 'app' is an Android project without build variants

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting below error while importing android project.

Error:The module 'app' is an Android project without build variants, and cannot be built.
    Please fix the module's configuration in the build.gradle file and sync the project again.

Gradle file code.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.djalel.android.bilal"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 4
    versionName "1.3"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
    }
}

aaptOptions {
    cruncherEnabled = false
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:2.0.1'
implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:3.1.0'
}
repositories {
mavenCentral()
}
```

I checked with working gradle file as well but getting same error in this project.

Comment: It's an old one, but a good'un, try File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart, failing that you could try clearing your gradle cache manually.  If this is happening across multiple projects, that were working, this solution sounds most plausible.

Comment: Can you show the build.gradle for the application ? I would like to know which version of the gradle-plugin you are using `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:?'`

Comment: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Above gradle file code seems to be perfect. Probably its nothing to do with app/build.gradle (Module:app). Just open other build.gradle (Project:Android) file in Project window and verify your Android Studio version it must be same as yours.

I replaced from:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

to my Android Studio v3.0.1 in my case:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

Press "Try Again" to Sync gradle file. This resolved my problem with a successful build.

Comment: After few months got this error again and found this one really work.

Comment: Studio 4.0.1 and build:gradle 4.0.2 — Why, @Google? — a tiny version number difference like this can happen so quickly. There should be a proper error message.

Answer (score 25):

For me, this issue appeared when I updated Android Studio to version 3.3.
Disabling experimental feature "*Only sync the active variant*" fixes it:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That also worked for me!
This feature seems not to be mature right now.

Answer (score 23):

Try use command line to run `gradlew tasks` to see why the build would fail.

In my case:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
 platforms;android-27 Android SDK Platform 27
 build-tools;27.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.3
```

So I just ran Go to `Android\sdk\tools\bin` `sdkmanager --licenses` to accept licenses and then the build passed in command line.

I think Android Studio is crying for the wrong issue. So you may check the real output in command line and find what is happening.

Comment: for those who are working on a mac and having this issue, simply  sdkmanager --licenses solves it. You just need to accept all the licenses

Answer (score 4):

Just install the Android SDK platform package through SDK Manager in Android Studio, relevant to your Compile SDK version. It will prompt you to install the package as well as to accept the license. After that just sync the gradle, it will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You must update your dependencies in `build.grade` in the **buildscript** block:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
```

to:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

If this error occurs for other module than 'app'

Remove gradle variable from that module's build.gradle like

`implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"`

& replace it actual value

`implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.2.71"`

Clean Project -> Rebuild Project

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in my library project. I solved it by adding

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

To the beginning of `build.gradle`

Answer (score 0):

Once try to invalidate cache and restart android studio it might be because when fetching your code from git it might have  some issue in my case it worked for me.